# How to use <iframe> tag inside <a href=" ">

Tags: html, iframe, tags, href

So, my plan is to show some image on page and if user click on that image he will be redirected to some certain page of some website inside of format of that image.

I tryed something like this:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">
<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" width="665" height="235"></iframe>
</a>
```

But, obvious it's not working...

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element) forbids `<a>` elements from including *interactive content*, which includes `<iframe>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you are trying to do?

What I understood was, if someone tries to click on that iframe you want them to redirect to some other link!

For this, you can use JS. Wrap it inside Div and make onClick for that div and in that function you can do href to new location.

Comment: Please do not misuse the answer section for posting comments/questions. Instead wait until you have enough reputation to post comments

Comment: @Nandan Not sure can I use JS, because this iframe has to be sent to email.
User recive some mail with that image and if user click on img it will redirect him to some website.

Comment: Yup sorry, but I did gave a answer for this question

Comment: @NeoCortex Why are trying with Iframe. Email supports HTML, you can directly send it to users with a image and linking image to a webpage.

Comment: @Nandan I know and I done that on that way, but chief told me to do with iframe.

Answer (score 0):

add an id to you'r iframe

```
<iframe id="iframe_id" src=""></iframe>
```

and with js (jquery) add a function that do what u want

```
$('#iframe_id').click(function() {
    //your code 
})
```